# Extracting common expressions into variables

Tags: c++, coding-style

Say I have a pointer to a class object `JoeBloggs`, is it better to do calculations like this

```
int value = Factorize( (JoeBloggs->GetNumber()*CalculateHeight(57,88)) )*JoeBloggs->GetSpeed();
```

or

```
int currentSpeed = JoeBloggs->GetSpeed();
int currentNumber = JoeBloggs->GetNumber();

int value = Factorise( (currentNumber*CalculateHeight(57,88)) )*currentSpeed;
```

I have been using the top one since it is so much shorter, but there are quite
a few times when I think the second one results in much neater code. I am trying to 
stick to one consistent style of coding.

Comment: IMHO, it's too small to be broken. I would go with the first.

Comment: No objective answer possible. The first way _may_ be more efficient, but good compilers will do the same, the second can be optimized by marking both `int`s as `const` (allows the compiler to do more). Personally I prefer fewer characters per line (aim: the usual 80)

Comment: You don't have to be consistent... pick the one which is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you pass the pointer to function 'Factorise' which calculates the result.
In other words: encapsulation.

Comment: talking about encapsulation, in that case factorize should be a member function. BTW the example is unclear, but I wouldn't do this, as it probably doesn't belong there

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be consistent.

Sticking to your second rule is certainly not a good idea, as it makes the code incredibly verbose.

But you cannot enforce the first rule either, because expressions sometimes become complicated enough so you have to break them. This is especially true if you access a member of an object which was retrieved with a member function etc.. but then again, that could be a good sign that you're doing the work at the wrong place.

BTW there are other rules for breaking code into pieces, by naming things. If you give a name for the first part of your expression, then readers will understand what the hell are you doing - for this rule your example is perfect, because I have no idea what you're doing...

```
int calculatedheight = Factorize( (JoeBloggs->GetNumber()*CalculateHeight(57,88));
int value = calculatedheight*JoeBloggs->GetSpeed();
```

... and the same argument goes for `value`.. what's that? it's a completely meaningless variable name.

I highly recommend Martin Fowler's articles and book about refactoring, it has plently of examples which show you how to do this the right way. The rule I mentioned is called [Introduce Explaining Variable](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceExplainingVariable.html).

Answer (score 0):

good code is not a short code. good code is readable code. code is being read about 10 times often than written. if it's a real life commercial application then you will read this code many times in the future and you will have to again fully understand what that code does. from that perspective, which version is easier to understand for you and your team?